# Open a MacVim (gvim) window from MacVim

Tags: vi, macvim

On Ubuntu/Windows when I have a gvim window open I just type `:!gvim filename` to open a new window.

On OSX this does nothing.

I think it may have to do with OSX not liking multiple instances of the same program, but it lets me open all the gvim windows I want manually from terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `:!mvim filename` (or `!gvim filename`) works for me, but I have the commands set up in /usr/local/bin (and /usr/local/bin in PATH), and I don't remember the installation instructions for where to get the script to put there. If you don't have that, try `:!open -a MacVim filename`, but this only works on existing files.

Also you can open a new window with <kbd>⌘N</kbd> or `:macaction newWindow:`, but that won't let you specify a filename, and the working directory will be your home directory.

Comment: `:!open -a MacVim filename` worked fabulously. The only problem is you can't open the *same* file this way, but that's not a huge problem. `:!open -a MacVim %` doesn't work. Overall I can work around that by just opening up the current directory with `:!open -a MacVim .`. My workflow is to open a new window and then `ctrl-p` to the new file I'm looking for

Comment: A week or so later and I'm really not happy with this workflow :p I'd really like to be able to open up files with params like line number but `open` doesn't support args (try it, nothing works, I know the docs say it should work with --args)

Comment: @CornSmith There's a "mvim" script inside the app bundle that you can copy or link into /usr/local/bin to allow it to be opened from the command line. But i'm not sure how you're able to open it from the terminal already but not from within vim, check what $PATH is.

Comment: I mean, it's in the $PATH since if I type `:!gvim something` it doesn't error, it just doesn't do anything. Same with `mvim`. It's like gvim is somehow making it impossible to spawn more gvim windows from itself.

Comment: @CornSmith Weird. It works for me.

Comment: So if you open gvim you can type :!gvim % and it'll open a second window with the same file? If so can you let me know how you installed gvim? I just used brew

Comment: I think I installed it from the macvim release page i.e. http://macvim-dev.github.io/macvim/. I might have had to copy/link "mvim" from the app bundle into /usr/local/bin myself to get the command line working.

Comment: I just installed the latest version and I get the same behavior :( even when I run it with the full path like this: `:!/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim myfile.py`. It just runs the command without error, but nothing happens. I did however get something working :) something really bad. I made a python service that I can send commands to and it'll run them. It uses `zmq` to do it and it's just a few lines long. Using that I can send the gvim command to it and it works. Lmao what have I done

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally solve it (hackily) by launching it from another python process. The problem is something to do with one macvim instance not releasing python properly.

https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12792/12803

I know it's usually bad form to post a link as an answer, but since it's another stackexachange link I'm not sure